# Transition overlayed by background fade

Tags: android, android-transitions

When I make an Activity scene transition, my problem is that while the Shared Element Transition is running, the other elements fade out. I found out that they don't really fade out, but the background of the second activity fades in.

When I set the background fade duration of the second activity to a very long time, I don't see the elements being covered. But thats not a real solution but more of a hack. What can I do there?

Transition code is [starting here](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/blob/develop/audiobook/src/main/java/de/ph1b/audiobook/activity/BookShelfActivity.java#L291) and in the other activity is [receiving here](https://github.com/Ph1b/MaterialAudiobookPlayer/blob/develop/audiobook/src/main/java/de/ph1b/audiobook/activity/BookPlayActivity.java#L330).

Comment: What behavior would you like to achieve?

Comment: I cannot find any exitTransition defined in the first activity or in your styles.xml (norm and v21). So the enter transition is played immediately I suppose. please correct me if I'm wrong. I found only some shared element.